# Weird grey bottom line when using multiple layers of menu with :hover

Tags: html, css

My website's demo navigation bar is like this in here https://jsfiddle.net/xzfy2ee2/.

Since the options for 'Faunas' is continuing to grow, I think it may be better to create a side menu. So I used all sorts of css :hover to achieve the result.

Although the functionality is robust enough, there is a wired grey line just after 'Asia' when I move the mouse onto 'Faunas' and calls out the dropdown menu. It's still there when I move the mouse onto 'Asia' to show the side menu 'Japan'.

The HTML/CSS for the navigation bar is shown here:

```css
    #nav a:hover
    {
        color: Silver;
    }
    #nav ul
    {
        list-style-type:none;
        
    }
    
    #nav ul li
    {
        display: inline-block;    
    }
    
    #nav ul li:hover ul
    {
        display:block;
    }
    
    #nav ul ul
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #888888;
        border: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0;
        border-top:0;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right:2px;
        min-width:80px;
        
       
    }
    
    
    #nav ul ul li
    {
        display: block;
        
       
    }
    
    #nav ul ul ul li
    {
        display: none; 
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #888888;
        border: 0px solid #A0A0A0;
        border-top:0;
        margin-left:115px;
        margin-right:2px;
        margin-top:-20px;
        padding-right:5px;
        min-width:80px;
        
       
    }
    
    #nav ul ul li:hover ul li
    {
        display:block;
    }
    
    #nav ul ul ul li:hover
    {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href = "/Homepage/MainContent">Home</a></li>
    
        <li><a href="/Faunas/Main">Faunas</a>
    
          <ul style ="width:160px">
            <li style="border-bottom:1px solid white;margin-bottom:3px"><a href="/Faunas/Main">About</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom:1px solid white;margin-bottom:7px"><a href="/World/Main">World</a></li>
            <li style="border-bottom:1px solid white;margin-bottom:2px">
              <a href="/Faunas/Asia">Asia</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/Japan/Main">Japan</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/Albania/Main">Albania</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Bulgaria/Main">Bulgaria</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Chile/Main">Chile</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Colombia/Main">Colombia</a></li>
            <li><a href="/France/Main">France</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Italy/Main">Italy</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Japan/Main">Japan</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Macedonia/Main">Macedonia</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Poland/Main">Poland</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Serbia/Main">Serbia</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Slovenia/Main">Slovenia</a></li>
            <li><a href="/SouthAfrica/Main">South Africa</a></li>
            <li><a href="/UnitedKingdom/Main">United Kingdom</a></li>
            <li><a href="/UnitedStates/Main">United States</a></li>
          </ul>
    
        </li>
    
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I didn't find anything to do with the gray line. I wonder what exactly is the line there? And is there any way to remove it?

Comment: you need to understand parent child relationship between tags and how are they manipulated using css. I hope http://stackoverflow.com/a/42124254/6840615 this solves your problem and clarifies your concept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #888888;
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0; 
    border-top:0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:2px;
    min-width:80px;
    
   
}
```

In this part of code `border-bottom: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0;`  is the problem! It is causing the child `ul` tag to have border too!

**Solution:**

In css:

Border removed from `#nav ul ul` and added border to specific second `ul`

```
 #nav ul ul
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #888888;
    border-bottom: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0; 
    border-top:0;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right:2px;
    min-width:80px;


} 

#nav ul #second
{
    border: 2.5px solid red;
   
}
```

**In Html:**

Assign an `id` to the `ul`

```
<ul id="second" style ="width:160px" >
```

> If you just don't need the boder than delete `border-bottom: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0;`  this line from `#nav ul ul`

update at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzfy2ee2/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this is detailed and provided enough options! I'll go ahead and assign an id then. I really need to go over CSS basics again.

Answer (score 3):

you have unnecessary `border: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0;` applied to `#nav ul ul` (which covers both 1st and 2nd level dropdowns)

here's working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lt4udmpt/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `#nav ul ul border-bottom` element is the culprit.

```
#nav ul ul
{
border-bottom: 2.5px solid #A0A0A0; <-----delete
}
```